# Argument type number is not assignable to parameter type string | undefined Type number is not assignable to type string

Tags: javascript

I am bit confused with this warning:

`Argument type number is not assignable to parameter type string | undefined  Type number is not assignable to type string`

Take the following peace of code:

```
function createCalculator() {

    let calculator = {
        sum() {
            return this.a + this.b;
        },

        mul() {
            return this.a * this.b;
        },

        read() {
            this.a = +prompt('a?', 0);
            this.b = +prompt('b?', 0);
        }
    };

    calculator.read([1,3,6]);
    console.log( calculator.sum() );
    console.log( calculator.mul() );

}
let calculator;
calculator = createCalculator();
```

Also I have one warning:

```
Void function return value is used
```

I want the follow:

The function `createCalculator()` returns an object with three methods:

- `read(arr)` accepts a table of numbers and saves it in its field
  object.
- `sum()` returns the sum of the table values
- `mul()` returns the product of the table values

Comment: This code works fine for me though.

Comment: @Deepak You do not get the above warnings ? I have the above warning and when i run it i take the following : ReferenceError: prompt is not defined

Comment: No @mixalis, it works and gives me the expected sum and multiplication results.

Comment: @Deepak i use JS and when i run it i take the above ReferenceError: prompt is not defined

Comment: In which environment do you run your code? Does this help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54486307/referenceerror-prompt-is-undefined-how-would-i-fix-this-in-javascript

Comment: @Deepak I get the same error in atom and webstorm

Comment: Use [`parseInt`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt) to convert your input into a number.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### The warning is because your object constructor is not returning an object

I have inserted a return function which should make your warning disappear.

```js
function createCalculator() {

  let calculator = {
    sum() {
      return this.a + this.b;
    },

    mul() {
      return this.a * this.b;
    },

    read() {
      this.a = +prompt('a?', 0);
      this.b = +prompt('b?', 0);
    }
  };

  calculator.read(); // Don't bother to send in the [1,3,6] because you are not using it in the function.
  console.log(calculator.sum());
  console.log(calculator.mul());

  return calculator // Do this so that your final statement really has something to receive!

}

let calculator;
calculator = createCalculator();
```

#### Perhaps you intended to write this, though?

```js
function createCalculator() {

  return {
    sum() {
      return this.a + this.b;
    },

    mul() {
      return this.a * this.b;
    },

    read() {
      this.a = +prompt('a?', 0);
      this.b = +prompt('b?', 0);
    }
  };


}

const calculator = createCalculator();

calculator.read();
console.log(calculator.sum());
console.log(calculator.mul());
```

#### I now see you intended to read a list of values, rather than input them "live"

So how about this:

```js
function createCalculator() {
  return {

    memory: [],

    read(arr) {
      this.memory = arr
    },

    sum() {
      return this.memory.reduce((x, y) => x + y, 0)
    },

    mul() {
      return this.memory.reduce((x, y) => x * y, 1)
    },

  };
}

const calculator = createCalculator();

calculator.read([1, 3, 6]);
console.log(calculator.sum());
console.log(calculator.mul());
```